# Call C++ functions from Java

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, c++11, java-native-interface

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I am working on a project and I need your help in JNI. I got stuck there... I have been reading and trying it a lot recently, but still didn't figure out how to make it work.

I have created a static library in C++ (a pseudo-code is shown below):

```
// file: X.h    
class X {
    public:
        X() {};
        ~X() {};

        void fooX() { // do stuff };
        void barX() { // do more stuff };
}

// file: X.cpp
#include "X.h";

// file: Y.h 
#include "X.h"
class Y {
    public:
        Y() {x = new X()};
        ~Y() {};

        fooY() { // do stuff };
        barY() { // do more stuff };

    private:
        X x;    // object of class X
}

// file: Y.cpp
#include "Y.h"

// file: Z.h 
#include "Y.h"
class Z {
    public:
        Z(uint8_t, std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>);
        ~Z() {};

        fooZ() { // do stuff };
        barZ() { // do more stuff };

    private:
        Y y;    // object of class Y
}

// file: Z.cpp
#include "Z.h"
Z::Z(uint8_t a, std::string b, std::vector<uint8_t> c)
{
     /// do stuff and create an object of Y
     Y y = new Y();
}

// file api.h
#include "Z.h"
void accessZ(uint8_t, std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>);

// file api.cpp
#include "api.h"
void accessZ(uint8_t a_uint, 
     std::string b_string, 
     std::vector<uint8_t> c_vector)
{
     // create object of Z
     Z z = new Z(a_uint, b_string, c_vector);
     z->fooZ();

     delete z;
     z = NULL; 
}
```

Further, I have compiled all of the above code as a static library (libXYZ.a) in C++ (Eclipse C++ CDT on Windows 7 using MinGW).

Now, what I would like to have is to be able to call the API **accessZ()** C++ function from a Java application!
In other words, I have implemented the core functionality in C++ and I would like to implement the GUI in Java. Therefore, I need to access the C++ functions from the Java GUI...

***How can I do that?*** I need direct answers and not vague ones please...

Your help is very appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

**Edited**

My project is as follows:

```
                                MyLibrary
                                    |
Makefile        header/     source/        bin/       object/     lib/
                X.h         X.cpp                     X.o       libXYZ.a
                Y.h         Y.cpp                     Y.o
                Z.h         Z.cpp                     Z.o
                api.h       api.cpp                   api.o
```

All what I need is to be able to pass some parameters from Java to **libXYZ** using the **accessZ()** function.

**New Edit:**

```
public final class NativeClass {
  {
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
  }

  public native void accessZ(char a_uint, String b_string, char[] c_vector);

  public static final NativeClass getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  private static final NativeClass INSTANCE = new NativeClass();
};
```

Comment: Did you look in any of the existing jni tutorials? Why do you expect us to write down stuff explicitly for you... That was written down a zillion times before?

Comment: @GhostCat : Of course I have checked JNI tutorials. However, all of them address a specific function written in C++ and not a function in a library.

Comment: And within these tutorials... The c++ functions used there... Are not stored in some library or dll -  they just live in some vacuum?!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comments and time... I am totally new to JNI. So, if you know/have some useful links/tutorials (not like HelloWorld JNI example) that address my question please put it there; probably, I have missed some search results... Else, I have no time to get into useless discussions...

Comment: You must show us what you've tried so far, i.e. the Java code which calls the C++ function. As a word of advice, it may be better to start your experiments with a *very* simple function like `int getInt() { return 123; }`. Otherwise, it's unclear what kind of answer you expect from us that would not reproduce numerous existing free online tutorials or textbook chapters about JNI. Remember, Stack Overflow is about *specific* problems. You should also not sound so demanding. I mean, *"I need direct answers"*, come on... it's not like you are paying us money for this.

Comment: What do you mean by the difference between accessing a function from a library and any other function?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a function like this directly, the function you will call from JNI will have to have a particular name and a particular form and will have to be represented by a member function in some Java class. (Also, Java does not have unsigned integers, so your `uint8_t` would have to be probably `char` or some other primitive type, and similarly you'll need to think what will represent the `std::vector` in Java.) But it's perfectly OK to

1. make the Java function publicly accessible (unfortunately, it can't be static, a class instance is important),
2. have the native implementation do nothing else than extract the parameters and call `accessZ()`.

Typically, your code will look something like

```
public final class NativeClass {

  {
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
  }

  public native void accessZ(char a_uint, String b_string, char[] c_vector);

  public static final NativeClass getInstance {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  private static final NativeClass INSTANCE = new NativeClass();

};
```

Then your `myLibrary.cpp` will have to include `<jni.h>` and `"api.h"` and to contain a function along the lines of

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeClass_accessZ(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jchar ja_uint, jstring jb_string, jcharArray jc_vector) {

  uint8_t a_uint = (uint8_t)ja_uint;

  const char *cfn = env->GetStringUTFChars(jb_string, 0);
  std::string b_string{cfn};
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jb_string, cfn);

  size_t sz = env->GetArrayLength(jc_vector);
  std::vector<uint8_t> c_vector(sz);
  jchar *c_array = env->GetCharArrayElements(jc_vector, NULL);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    c_vector[i] = c_array[i];
  env->ReleaseCharArrayElements(jc_vector, c_array, 0);

  accessZ(a_uint, b_string, c_vector);

}
```

wrapped in an `extern "C"` block. Your JNI tutorial will tell you how to go about making a dynamic library out of it and helping Java find it. Just link the other parts of your project (`libXYZ.a`) with it statically when creating the `.dll` (i.e., list the archive among the sources). You can then call from within Java for example:

```
NativeClass.INSTANCE.accessZ((char)10, "abc", new char[]{3, 5, 7});
```

***This function will become the access point of your library*** but then can do whatever it wants, it can create objects, call functions on them, it may even keep a transient state because your library will keep running between the calls. (It's better to operate on a state object passed to the function, though.) There may be arbitrarily many of functions exposed by the library to Java like this.

Here are my command lines (for Linux):

```
g++ -isystem /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/include/ -isystem /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/include/linux myLibrary.cpp -c -fPIC
(creates myLibrary.o)

g++ myLibrary.o libXYZ.a -shared -o libmyLibrary.so
(creates libmyLibrary.so)
```

Comment: Hi @The Vee,
thanks a lot for your reply. I will try it later today (if I have time) and get back to you. Indeed, in the mean while, I just need to pass the parameters from Java to C++ with **accessZ()** function returning nothing (i.e., void). Later, when I finish this step (Java -> C++ communication), I would like the **accessZ()** to return a boolean; but now I am focusing on a single part of the problem. Cheers.

Comment: @M_Square My code contained some errors. I now tested it and fixed them so please try with the new version instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts. I have tried yesterday (many times with different settings) to compile with javah but the class you provided above is not compiling... I am getting the following error when I run `javah -jni NativeClass.java`:

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: can't find class file NativeClass/java.class in java.net.URLClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.getClass(libgcj-tools.so.16)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.parseClasses(libgcj-tools.so.16)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.run(libgcj-tools.so.16)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.javah.Main.main(libgcj-tools.so.16)`

**Any ideas?**
BR

Comment: @M_Square That's a strange name, `NativeClass/java.class`. This is a "file not found" error, not related what's *in* the file. Do you have no problem compiling other classes? Did you have `NativeClass` follow the same file naming conditions? If it's a public class in package `x.y.z` it needs to be found in a file named `x/y/z/NativeClass.java`. (Also, the name of the C method would be `Java_x_y_z_NativeClass_accessZ`.) In my example it's not in any package.

Comment: I have no problem compiling other java classes. Yes, the class name NativeClass has the same name of the file NativeClass.java. I think that it may be the problem that the class has no **main()** method. or?

Comment: @M_Square No, just one class in your project is required to provide the `main()`. I think I know what to look for. Can you post your codebase somewhere? I'd have a look.

Comment: in any case, I have just the class - please check question edit, file name (NativeClass.java).

Comment: I try first to compile using: `javac NativeClass.java` it works. But when I run `javah -jni NativeClass.java`, I get the error above!

Comment: @M_Square I see! You wouldn't need `javah`. But if you want to call it then give it a class name, not file name: `javah -jni NativeClass`